# Dynamically add x-axis in React using ChartJS

Tags: reactjs, charts, dataset, chart.js, x-axis

I want to add another x axis to my ChartJS which works, but the scales do not separate, for example I want one label on the x-axis with 0-9 and another one 0-16 to show separately. It works perfectly fine for the y-axis but not for the x-axis.[image: This is an image which shows that the seperate y axes work but not the x axes]

Now for the code:
here I create an initial state

```
let state = {
          labels: [],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'ignore',
              
              fill: false,
              lineTension: 0,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(109, 24, 172, 1)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(109, 24, 172, 1)',
              borderWidth: 0.1,
              pointRadius: 0.2,
              data: []
            }, {
              label: 'ignore1',
              fill: false,
              lineTension: 0,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 250, 255, 1)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 250, 255, 1)',
              borderWidth: 0.1,
              pointRadius: 0.2,
              data: []
            }
          ]
        };
```

Here is my first function with 9 datapoints:

```
function adddataset(){
      let lineChart = Chart.instances[0];
      const data=lineChart.data;
      const newDataset = {
        label: 'Dataset ' + (data.datasets.length + 1),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(109, 24, 172, 1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 250, 255, 1)',
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        yAxisID: 'By',
        xAxisID: 'Bx',
      };
      lineChart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
      lineChart.update();
    }
```

here is my second function to add a second dataset:

```
function adddataset1(){
      let lineChart = Chart.instances[0];
      const data=lineChart.data;
      const newDataset = {
        label: 'Dataset ' + (data.datasets.length + 1),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(rgba(109, 24, 172, 1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(109, 24, 172, 1)',
        data: [100,30,50,60,20,30,60,100,34,3456,6,5,4,3,5,545],
        
        yAxisID: 'Cy',
        xAxisID: 'Cx',
    
        
      };
      lineChart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
      
      lineChart.update();
    }
```

now here is my class where I initialize the LineGraph and have 2 buttons which call the functions

```
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (

      <body>
        <main>
          Graph
          <div className='Graph'>
            <div style={{ height: 500 }}>
              <Line
                id="mychart"
                data={state}
                options={{
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Average Rainfall per month',
                    fontSize: 20
                  },
                  legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'right'
                  },

                  maintainAspectRatio: false,
                  responsive: true
                }}
              />
            </div>

          </div>
          <button onClick={adddataset1}>
            Button1
          </button>
          <button onClick={adddataset}>
            Button2
          </button>
        </main>
      </body>
    );
  }
}
export default About;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for your problem, you can either provide your data in object format so the labels get taken from the object like so:

```js
const data = [{x: '1', y: 5}, {x: '2', y: 3}];
```

Or you can add a second x axis with the correct ID to all the scales which has a labels array property in which you can specify the labels for that scale so you will get something like this:

```js
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});

myChart.options.scales['secondX'] = {
  labels: ['6', '7', '8'],
  position: 'bottom'
}

myChart.update();
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the second approach and it works!